# Json Deserialization of Encapsulated object in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

In my c# project, I have a json object in the following format:

```json
{
  "Name" : "TestUser",
  "Description": "Testing",
  "Address": {
    "city": "Paris",
    "country": "France"
  }
}
```

And I have created classes corresponding to it:

```
class User
{
  string Name;
  string Description;
  Address Address;
}

class Adress
{
   double lat;
   double long;
}
```

And I want to have a custom json deserializer for `Address` class. While deserializing the User class, the address object should be populated from my custom logic.

Is there any way to do that without writing custom resolver for the `User` class itself?
Possibly if I can have a method that takes `JToken` as input and enables me to create Address object out of it.

```
public Address DeserializeAddress(JToken jtoken)
{
   ...
   return address;
}
```

I am using `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method of Newtonsoft library.

Comment: Check [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConverterAttributeClass.htm)

Comment: As a city and country are not exactly alternate representations of a latitude and longitude (or vice versa) it seems like a distinctly unnatural choice to put this on the serialization logic. I'd map the thing straightforwardly and apply the logic that adds/looks up the location explicitly, afterwards.